# Python : Something unexpected is happening in my code....?

Tags: python, oop, logic, control-flow

I am teaching myself oop concepts. So i have a inner class Laptop inside my Student class. My student class saves student info and laptop class saves their laptop configuration. I pass all the required arguemnts through a student object(name, rollno, brand, cpu, ram). I have a method that show all of these information passed. But something unexpected is happening..

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, rollno, brand, cpu, ram):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.lap = self.Laptop(brand, cpu, ram)

    def show(self):
        print(self.name, self.rollno, self.lap.show())

    class Laptop():
        def __init__(self, brand, cpu, ram):
            self.brand = brand
            self.cpu = cpu
            self.ram = ram

        def show(self):
            print(self.brand, self.cpu, self.ram)

 s1 = Student('Mayank', '1654302036', 'H.P', 'i3', '4gb')
 s1.show()
```

My output is..

```
H.P i3 4gb
Mayank 1654302036 None
```

I dont why my details of Laptop are being shown first.

Comment: Because `self.lap.show()` prints its output, it doesn't return it. You should rather return messages than print them directly in your methods. Also, why create an inner class?

Answer (score 2):

`self.lap.show()` is evaluated (and calls `print` itself) before the call to `print` in `Student.show` begins.

Usually, you don't use `print` "deep" in your code; return a `str` instead, and let someone *else* decide whether to print it or not.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, rollno, brand, cpu, ram):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.lap = self.Laptop(brand, cpu, ram)

    def show(self):
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.name, self.rollno, self.lap.show())

    class Laptop():
        def __init__(self, brand, cpu, ram):
            self.brand = brand
            self.cpu = cpu
            self.ram = ram

        def show(self):
            return "%s %s %s" % (self.brand, self.cpu, self.ram)


s1 = Student('Mayank', '1654302036', 'H.P', 'i3', '4gb')
print(s1.show())
```

However, if you really have a good reason for `show` to call print immediately, don't pass `self.lap.show()` as a argument to print. Print the
student information first, then call `lap.show()`.

```
def show(self):
    print(self.name, self.rollno)
    self.lap.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you cleared all my douts.)))

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your show methods are using the `print()` function, and not returning a string. What happens is the following:

- When calling `s1.show()`, the interpreter wants to build a string in the `Student.show()` method.
- For doing so, it will evaluate all the arguments given to the `print()`function. This includes the call to the `Laptop.show()` method. But since this method is not *returning* a string but directly *printing*, this inner call will write to your terminal first.
- Finally, the output of the initial call is ready to be sent to the ouptut.

The best way to correct this behavior would be to overwrite the `__str__` method for each of those class. This method, which is used under the hood when printing any object in Python, has to *return* a string object, and not printing it as it is the case here. Here is what you might do:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, rollno, brand, cpu, ram):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.lap = self.Laptop(brand, cpu, ram)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.rollno + ' ' + self.lap.__str__()

    class Laptop():
        def __init__(self, brand, cpu, ram):
            self.brand = brand
            self.cpu = cpu
            self.ram = ram

        def __str__(self):
            return self.brand + ' ' + self.cpu + ' ' + self.ram
```

Then calling `s1.__str__()` or 
equivalently `print(s1)` will output the expected result.